# How to substitute values from one data.frame by values of another one?

Tags: r, merge, dplyr

I have two data.frames - first one is coded:

```
correlations <- data.frame(var1 = c('a','a','a','b','e'), var2 = c('b','c','d','e','c'), r = runif(5,0.5,1))
correlations

var1 var2          r
   a    b  0.6702400
   a    c  0.7301086
   a    d  0.5727880
   b    e  0.5916388
   e    c  0.5510549
```

and second one contains key for that codes:

```
D <- data.frame(code = letters[1:5],name=c('setosa','bulbifer','rubra','minor','nigra'))
D

  code     name
   a     setosa
   b   bulbifer
   c      rubra
   d      minor
   e      nigra
```

I need to recode the first data set `D` by the variables `code` and `name` within the second data.frame.
Result:

```
     var1     var2          r
   setosa bulbifer  0.6702400
   setosa    rubra  0.7301086
   setosa    minor  0.5727880
 bulbifer    nigra  0.5916388
    nigra    rubra  0.5510549
```

I have no idea how to achieve this (I need some function like merge, substitute, Map or others, but nothing suits to this).

Comment: How many columns you have in `correlations` in real life?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this with the library `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)

D <- left_join(correlations, D, by=c("var1" ="code")) %>% 
  left_join(D, by=c("var2" ="code")) %>% select(name.x, name.y, r) %>% 
  rename(var1=name.x, var2=name.x)
```

The logic is: join twice with `correlations` one on the `var1` and then on `var2`. Then drop the old `var1` and `var2` then rename the new vars.

Comment: Very nice! I must learn more about this funciton. I have heard about left join, but not in connection with R and I didn't imagine that it could be that easy... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Alternately you can `merge` twice? Use "var1" instead of "code" as column name in code table.

```
correlations <- data.frame(var1 = c('a','a','a','b','e'), var2 = c('b','c','d','e','c'), r = runif(5,0.5,1))
D <- data.frame(var1 = letters[1:5],name=c('setosa','bulbifer','rubra','minor','nigra'))

output1 <- merge(D, correlations, by = "var1", all.y = TRUE)
output1$var1 <- NULL
names(output1)[2] = "var1"
output2 <- merge(D, output1, by = "var1", all.y = TRUE)

> output2
  var1   name.x   name.y         r
1    b bulbifer   setosa 0.7328087
2    c    rubra   setosa 0.9492819
3    c    rubra    nigra 0.5884522
4    d    minor   setosa 0.9501921
5    e    nigra bulbifer 0.9266531
```